# Exported jar file is not visible in JUnit request sampler

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

i try to select class file in jmeter junit request sampler.i want help how to choose my class file in junit request sampler

i export the package and stored it in apache lib->junit folder
then,restart the jmeter, but my class file is not visible in junit request sampler and i import all the selenium jar files into the project including selenium standalone jar.

```
    @Test
         public void performence()
        {

        WebDriver driver=new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
        System.out.println( driver.getTitle());
        }

}
```

please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main issue is probably you didn't put dependencies (Webdriver) of your JUnit classes in lib folder.

Check jmeter.log to see what the error is and clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you..i put my all webdriver jar files in jmeter lib folder. its working fine.thank you so much for your help..

Answer (score 0):

1. Try checking `Search for JUnit 4 annotations (instead of JUnit3)` box (it is not checked by default hence JMeter is looking for JUnit3-style annotations)

   [image]
2. Make sure your class has an [empty constructor](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/constructors.html) or constructor with a single [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) parameter. Other class types are not supported as of JMeter 5.0
3. Make sure to place the .jar with your test into `lib/junit` folder of your JMeter installation and other libraries (i.e. Selenium java client) to `lib` folder of your JMeter installation. Carefully select dependency libraries versions in order to avoid so called [JAR Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) as JMeter and Selenium might rely on different versions of the same library.

   JMeter restart will be required to pick up any changes
4. Check [*jmeter.log*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) file for any suspicious entries. In the absolute majority of cases JMeter will print the information regarding the error or failure there.
5. See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) article for more information on JUnit and JMeter integration.

---

If you don't have large number of JUnit-based tests which you want to import into JMeter and you're starting development from scratch it might be easier to go for [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin which provides JMeter with smooth Selenium support and possibility to write Selenium-related code in variety of languages including Java.

You can install WebDriver Sampler plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Comment: i misseed my webdriver dependencies in junit lib folder.now i put all webdriver dependencies in lib folder its working fine. thankq for your replay